# No acepta la clase para ejecutar la aplicacion, Python y QtDesigner

Tags: python

Se trata sobre mi proyecto final, segui un tutorial en youtube y al final me lanza diferentes errores, trabajo con QtDesigner, PyQt5 y Python. No encuentro la solucion y trato de guiarme de diferentes modelos, ya he repetido el diseño de la aplicacion dos veces. El codigo donde modifico las funciones de los botones es el siguiente:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QEasingCurve
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VentanaPrincipal, self).__init__()
        loadUi('proyecto.ui', self)

        #mover menu
        self.bt_menu_uno.clicked.connect(self.mover_menu)
        self.bt_menu_dos.clicked.connect(self.mover_menu)

        #ocultamos botones
        self.bt_menu_dos.hide()

        #control barra de titulo
        self.bt_minimizar.clicked.connect(self.control_bt_minimizar)
        self.bt_maximizar.clicked.connect(self.control_bt_maximizar)
        self.bt_cerrar.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())

        #eliminar la barra de titulo
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowOpacity(1)

        #sizegrip
        self.gripSize = 10
        self.grip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)
        self.grip.resize(self.gripSize, self.gripSize)

        #mover ventana
        self.frame_superior.mouseMoveEvent = self.mover_ventana

        #acceder a las ventanas
        self.bt_uno.clicked.connect(self.page_uno())
        self.bt_dos.clicked.connect(self.page_dos())
        self.bt_salir.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())

    def control_bt_minimizar(self):
        self.showMinimized()

    def control_bt_maximizar(self):
        self.showMaximized()


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        rect = self.rect()
        self.grip.move(rect.right() - self.gripSize, rect.bottom() - self.gripSize)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clickPosition = event.globalPos()

    def mover_ventana(self, event):
       if self.isMaximized() == False:
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButtom:
                self.move(self.pos() + event.globalPos() - self.clickPosition)
                self.clickPosition = event.globalPos()
                event.accept()
       if event.globalPos().y() <= 10:
           self.showMaximized()

       else:
           self.showNormal()

    def mover_menu(self):
        if True:
            width = self.frame_2.width()
            normal = 0
            if width == 0:
                extender = 300
                self.bt_menu_dos.hide()
                self.bt_menu_uno.show()
            else:
                self.bt_menu_dos.show()
                self.bt_menu_uno.hide()
                extender = normal
            self.animacion = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_2, b"maximumWidth")
            self.animacion.setStartValue(width)
            self.animacion.setEndValue(extender)
            self.animacion.setDuration(500)
            self.animacion.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutInBack)  #InQuad, InOutQuad, InCubic, InOutExpo
            self.animacion.start()

    def page_uno(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrenWidget(self.page_uno)

    def page_dos(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrenWidget(self.page_dos)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app = VentanaPrincipal()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A la final me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 97, in <module>
    mi_app = VentanaPrincipal()
   line 39, in __init__
    self.bt_uno.clicked.connect(self.page_uno())
TypeError: 'QWidget' object is not callable
```

Comment: El error te lo dice claramente, estas pasando el resultado de llamar ala función y se necesita de un objeto *callable*,tal y como lo haces para `bt_salir`. Sería algo así `self.bt_uno.clicked.connect(lambda: self.page_uno())`

Comment: cuando llamas a una función no lleva los paréntesis:  self.bt_uno.clicked.connect(self.page_uno)

Comment: Gracias, ya no me sale el error pero ahora con cada boton que presiono el programa se cierra sin ejecutar nada de lo que se le pide, me podrian ayudar con un codigo o algo que conozcan?

Comment: se cierra tu codigo porque en el constructor estas ejecutando el metodo self.close() en la asignacion de funciones a botones. para evitar el llamado inmediato de estos metodos en el constructor debes simplemente eliminar sus parentesis "( )". ejemplo : ``self.bt_dos.clicked.connect(self.page_dos( ) )  --> self.bt_dos.clicked.connect(self.page_dos  ). esta eliminacion de parentesis del argumento pasado a connect debe realizarse en cada uno, de otra forma, se ejecutara la funcion al iniciar el programa

Answer (score 0):

No sé si aun presentes el inconveniente, veo que lo que quieres es configurar dos botones (bt_uno y bt_dos) para cambiar de pagina en el stackedWidget.

Debes eliminar las funciones page_uno y page_dos, y configurar directamente en el como método del constructor, borra las líneas 39 y 40.

```
self.bt_uno.clicked.connect(self.page_uno())
self.bt_dos.clicked.connect(self.page_dos())
```

Y las reemplazas por las siguientes:

```
self.bt_uno.clicked.connect(lambda:self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_uno))
self.bt_dos.clicked.connect(lambda:self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_dos))
```